# How to invoke forEach inside the service in angular

Tags: arrays, angularjs, foreach, ionic-framework

I am able to invoke in first foreach loop but not able to invoke in second forEach loop,Invoking two times the same forEach loop.

Can any one help me where I am doing mistak.

**Code:**

```
.service('delt', function($localStorage){
  return{
          deleteItem: function (id) {
            console.log(id);
            quickItems=[];
    $localStorage.quick.forEach(function(item, index){
      console.log(index);
      if(item.id == id){
        console.log(item.id + "==" + id);
        $localStorage.quick.splice(index,1);
        console.log("Deleted item " + item.title);
      }
    })
      console.log("aftrer costsum : " +costSum);

          console.log(quickItems);
         quickItems.forEach(function(element, index){
          console.log(element);
          console.log(index);
         costSum += Number(element.price)*Number(element.count);
         console.log(quickItems);
         console.log("enddd");
    });
       var costSum = 0;
       costSum =costSum.toFixed(2);
       console.log(costSum);
    var quickCount = $localStorage.quick.length;
    console.log(quickCount);
     return quickCount;
     //return costSum;
  }
  };

});
```

here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXlou.png) which my console is printed you can see i getting printed two times

Answer (score 0):

your quickItems array is empty to begin with, and is not populated before your second .forEach()

Comment: Actually I want to use two forEach in single service one for 'delete' and second one for 'price update'. Delete is working but price is not updating means i m not getting any return for price update. even in our code not entering in secon forEach loop.